# Windows App SDK: SpeechSynthesizer takes forever to synthesize

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

As I described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/discussions/8269):

> I have a method `async SpeakAsync(string language, string text)`:
>
> ```cs
>  var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
>  var player = new MediaPlayer();
>  SetVoice(language, ref synth);
>  var source = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
>  player.SetStreamSource(source);
>  synth.Dispose();
>  player.MediaEnded += (_, _) => { source.Dispose(); player.Dispose(); }
>  player.Play();
> ```
>
> If I call this method twice with `.Wait()` followed, my app will stuck at `var source = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);` forever for the second call (the first call runs perfectly).

I did [what @DarranRowe said](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/discussions/8269#discussioncomment-5273146) with storing a `MediaPlayer` instance and a `SpeechSynthesisStream` instance in a field of my class. I set the `SpeechSynthesisStream` instance to `null` at every time the method got called. But the problem still exists, and I don't know why this would solve my problem.

*Please comment or answer here, the GitHub discussion I referenced above is not a place for this question.*

Comment: You should post a full reproducible sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier I just edited my question and uploaded a repro to GitHub. May you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the `SpeechSynthetizer`, but is related to the [code](https://github.com/AkiraVoid/Test.WinUI3/blob/master/Test/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L56) you're using to call your method:

```
private void OnClick(object _sender, RoutedEventArgs _e)
{
    SpeakAsync("en-US", "Test 1").Wait();
    SpeakAsync("en-US", "Test 2").Wait();
}
```

It's using an `async` method with task `Wait()` from a UI thread which causes a deadlock.

This is a classic mistake (same as with Winforms or WPF), see this [How to avoid WinForm freezing using Task.Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793434/how-to-avoid-winform-freezing-using-task-wait) or [Winforms call to async method hangs up program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456194/winforms-call-to-async-method-hangs-up-program) on this site or [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) for a more detailed answer.

So the solution is just to do this instead:

```
private async void OnClick(object _sender, RoutedEventArgs _e)
{
    await SpeakAsync("en-US", "Test 1");
    await SpeakAsync("en-US", "Test 2");
}
```

Note with existing code, both phrases will play together, here's a version that can optionally wait for the end of play:

```
private Task SpeakAsync(string language, string text, bool waitForEnd = true)
{
    if (waitForEnd)
    {
        var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource();
        Task.Run(() => Do(tsc));
        return tsc.Task;
    }
    return Do(null);

    async Task Do(TaskCompletionSource tsc)
    {
        var player = new MediaPlayer();
        using var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        synth.Voice = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Language == language) ?? SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice;
        var source = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
        player.MediaEnded += (sender, _) =>
        {
            source.Dispose();
            tsc?.SetResult();
        };
        player.SetStreamSource(source);
        player.Play();
    }
}
```